# How to get the length of words in a sentence?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the length of each word in a sentence. I know you can use the "len" function, I just don't know how to get the length of each word.

Instead of this

```
>>> s = "python is pretty fun to use"
>>> len(s)
27
>>>
```

I'd like to get this

```
6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3
```

which is the actual length of every word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) for applying [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#len) over each word in the sentence, understanding that [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) creates a list with each word in the sentence:

```
s = "python is pretty fun to use"
map(len, s.split())       # assuming Python 2.x
list(map(len, s.split())) # assuming Python 3.x
```

Or alternatively, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the same effect:

```
[len(x) for x in s.split()]
```

In both cases the result is a list with the length of each word in the sentence:

```
[6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Actually, map returns a map object, not a list. You need to explicitly convert it to a list.

Comment: @AlexThornton that depends on what version of Python you're using. In Python 2.x it returns a list, in Python 3.x it returns an iterator

Comment: Thanks, this one was pretty helpful

Answer (score 8):

Use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)<sup>1</sup> and [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> s = "python is pretty fun to use"
>>> map(len, s.split())
[6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3]
>>>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*Note*: `map` returns an iterator in Python 3. If you are using that version, you may want to place it in `list` to get a list of integers like the Python 2 `map` returns:

```
>>> # Python 3 interpreter
>>> s = "python is pretty fun to use"
>>> map(len, s.split())
<map object at 0x02364ED0>
>>> list(map(len, s.split()))
[6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
s = "python is pretty fun to use"
[len(x) for x in s.split()]
```

example output:

```
>>> [len(x) for x in s.split()]
[6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3]
```

#### What's going on in the background?

[`s.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) breaks on the white space in the string and returns each word in the sentence in a list:

```
>>> s.split()
['python', 'is', 'pretty', 'fun', 'to', 'use']
```

Then we take the [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#len) of each of those words to get the word's length. After that, we take each length and append it to a list so that it can be conveniently returned as the result.

That all happens in this [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[len(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Still a little confused? This is conceptually the same thing just broken down more explicitly:

```
results = []
for x in s.split():
    word_length = len(x)
    results.append(word_length)
print results
```

If you'd like them printed out separately, like in your question, use:

```
for x in [len(x) for x in s.split()]: 
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

iCodez is right - but it requires a few minor adjustments from script form.

```
s = 'python is pretty fun to use'
li = list(map(len, s.split()))
```

then type into the shell or print statement:

```
print(li)
```

Comment: Oh -  and btw I learnt something too via this post. That I can help.